# Blank data stored by mysql query in form page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

The form is meant to capture a new user and store user data in the database, except that it does not store any data though the form still returns a successful message.

Form page:

```
<?php

$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$database = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";


 ?>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <section class="panel">
        <header class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Laai Nuwe Lid</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="" 
method="post">

                <p><strong>ID:</strong> Nuwe lid</p>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="FirstName">Naam:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                        </div>
                </div>  


                                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="LastName">Van:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="LastName" id="LastName" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"'>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="Cell">Selfoon:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="Cell" id="Cell" value="<?php echo $cell; ?>">
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" 
for="Address">Addres:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="Address" id="Address" value="<?php echo $adress; ?>">
                        </div>
                </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <button value="submit" type="submit" 
name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Stoor nuwe lid</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn- 
default">Kanselleer</button>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</div>


<?php

// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the 
form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$firstname = 
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
$lastname = 
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']));
$cell = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cell']));
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));


$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblusers` (FirstName, LastName, Cell, Address) VALUES 
('$firstname','$lastname', '$cell','$address')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: index.php");

}      
?>
```

I am not sure if the problem is with PHP or the SQL code as I get no error messages.

The database connects fine. The query works in mysql directly, but when I combine the PHP with the HTML form it stores blank rows.

Comment: Since the connection and the queries is inside `else`, how will you insert the data in the database in the `if` syntax?

Comment: One more thing, are all those codes supposed to be in a single page?

Comment: As @Swellar says, you've put all the code to update the database in the `else` clause of this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` so if you submit any data it can't get into the database.

Comment: you are mixing two different database API: mysql and mysqli. mysql have been deprecated long ago and removed in php 7. Your code probably fails already in the variable definition

Comment: you are open to sql injections. You should use prepared statements (available both with mysql and PDO) to sanitize your inputs

Comment: @Swellar do you have a better way of doing this?

Comment: I have moved the connection code out of the if and now it creates a row in the database, the fields are empty however, it creates blank rows in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was not working is because the variables were not the same, PHP is case sensitive. E.G lastname while HTML was LastName.

```
$firstname = 
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['FirstNameirstname']));
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['LastName']));
$cell = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['Cell']));
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['Address']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work because when you tried to comment out the validation part '**if condition**' you forgot to comment out its '**else condition**'.

I am talking about this line:

```
//if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $cell == '' || $address == '') {
```

Answer (score -3):

Kindly use the following function :

```
$con->mysqli_real_escape_string ( $_POST['...'])
```

in place of

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['...']))
```

Comment: Don't use either one. Use placeholders to bind user-supplied values to a query instead of inserting them directly in a string.  http://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: Also dont use $_POST directly. Use `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'post_data')` instead.